# Trying to get an SSL certificate from Comodo to work for Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, ssl

I am trying to use a SSL certificate from Comodo on my Google App Engine site.  I generated the key and the CSR with the following command:

```
openssl req -nodes -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout myserver.key -out server.csr
```

I then gave CSR file to them and they emailed me a CRT back.  I went to upload the certificate and google asked for a "PEM encoded X.509 certificate" and a "Unencrypted PEM encoded RSA private key" which I assumed were the .CRT and the .KEY files, respectively.  But when I try to upload them Google sends me the error message "Both the private key and SSL certificate should be in unencrypted PEM format."  I'm not sure what's going on.  Both  files contain the proper begin/end notation, and generally look like they're in PEM format